# Postman retrieve refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, refresh-token

I like to use the `OAuth` authentication support in Postman. It can retrieve access token for given `OAuth` inputs. As it also has to retrieve refresh token - after the first interactive phase - is it possible to get this token too (ideally somewhere from the UI)?

Would be comfortable to interactively negotiate refresh token and automatically retrieve access tokens, whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

OK, not exactly at the comfort level I wanted, but in the menu (v10.12.0):

`View | Developer | Show Dev Tools (Current View)`

then in the left sidebar:

`Storage | IndexedDB | postman-app - file:// | oauth_access_tokens`

we can find "random order DB table content" where, if we are lucky, we can also find the refresh tokens for the sessions originated from the Postman.